# Lead Function to Perform in DataStage

Tags: function, lag, datastage, lead

I am looking to do LEAD() and LAG() functions to perform in DataStage.

Input
C1 C2
1  100
2  200
3  300
4  400

Output - 1
C1 C2 C3
1 100 200
2 200 300
3 300 400
4 400 NULL

Output - 2
C1 C2 C3
1 100 NULL
2 200 100
3 300 200
4 400 300

Please help me getting this as I did tried with multiple ways using stage variables and loop variables but still unable to get it.

#DataStage #DataStage #LEAD #LAG

I did tried with multiple ways using stage variables and loop variables but still unable to get it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a transformer and its top down processing of the stage variables.

With is you can imitate a LEAD function. The LAG can be achieved by reversing the sort order which makes it a LEAD again.

The transformer processes row by row (if loops are not used) and you can access the previous row content - as stated above - by referencing a subsequent stage variable content fom a stage variable upfront.

I.e.
svFirst
svSecond

When svFirst is processed svSecond still has the content from the previous row.
So if you have something like svFirst = svSecond
you can access the data of the previous row.